# Execute code securely on client side

Tags: javascript, encryption, distributed-computing

I was asked this question on distributed computing at an interview.

Interviewer:

> "Sam ran a certain code on a client's computer to get its output. But 
>   the client modifies the code and hence the code returned a different output.
>
> Now Sam wants to know if its possible to detect whether the code had been 
>   changed or the return value is modified. Is this possible?"

I thought it was impossible to prevent the client from modifying the code since its on their computer. Or am i wrong? If not, can we detect whether the code has been changed or do something to  make it difficult for the client to manipulate the code and output?

Comment: It is impossible to prevent modification of the code.  And, from my experience, event with access to their machine it would be difficult to detect the changed code since it is not saved as a file as they change it.  I hope you see otherwise, this could be very cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter whether the client manipulates the code or not, the only thing that really counts is the *result* your server receives back from it. After all, the client may not be running your code at all, it may just return a hardcoded response.

So the question becomes: can your server trust **the answer** sent by the client?
The general answer is: no.

The more complex answer is: it depends on what you want it to do. Maybe what you're doing is amenable to the [proof-of-work concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system), in which a client has to mathematically proof that it did something. Maybe you can include some signing process which mathematically proves that certain data has been derived from certain other data and makes the client's data verifiable. Maybe the server can require two different clients to perform the same work or overlapping sections of work which can be verified against one another, which would require an attacker to manipulate two (or more) clients at once, which may be infeasible enough to make each client's response individually trustworthy.